# Wiring basic LED light to former ceiling fan box...too many wires?

Tags: electrical

Trying to replace a ceiling fan with a basic LED light that has black-white-green wires but I'm seeing so many wires in my box. What I do know is that the black to the left is ALWAYS hot, regardless of the light switch. The 3 wires to the right (black-white-bare) don't seem to power my LED light when I connect them solely to the light. I don't know what the white in the middle is for. All I'm trying to do is get the light switch to power the light...oh, and not kill myself in the process. Any ideas?[image][image: Switch box photo]

Comment: With the breaker off, can you measure continuity between the white and black wires on the right with the light switch in the ON position?

Comment: @threephaseeel how would I do that? Dealing with a novice here...also so you know I capped these with whatever caps were available just for safety - the red/yellow/orange caps have no significance.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: @threephaseeel I don't. Do I need it? Could grab one at Home Depot.

Comment: What switch controlled this light/fan? How many cables did it have coming into it?

Comment: The same switch that I'm trying to get to power the LED light. I haven't changed anything - only removed the ceiling fan that was there. Was hoping for a simple swap. The ceiling fan had a black-white-green-blue, and was grounded to itself. I didn't take a photo of how it was wired...stupidly.

Comment: Can you open up the switch box and post a photo of its insides?

Comment: Yes, added to original post.

Comment: Since you had a fan before, it's likely the fan took always-hot for the fan and remote control, and switched-hot for the light on the fan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Switch loops and you

The switch for your light was configured as an old style *switch loop* where the black wire is the always hot going out to the switch and the white wire is the switched hot coming back from the switch.  This was quite common before recent Code revisions mandated neutrals at most switch boxes in new construction (in order to power dimmers, timers, and other "smart switch" type gizmos).

Anyway, what you'll need to do is mark the single white wire in the light box and the white wire in the switch box with a few wraps of black electrical tape, then wire the single black wire from the wall cable to the black pigtail.  From there, you can connect the white wire on the fixture to the white pigtail, the black wire on the fixture to the taped white wire, and the green wire on the fixture to the bundle of bare wires, which should be redone using a proper wirenut anyway.  Button it all up, turn the breaker on, and enjoy your new light!

Comment: Un-freaking-believable! Worked just as you said. Wow...you're good...thank you!